# Invalid Set 'x' (on base:'bool') of value of type 'int'

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error, godot, gdscript, godot4

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var mon = Vector2.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    mon = move_and_slide()

    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        mon.x = -1  # Set the horizontal speed to -1
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        mon.x = 1   # Set the horizontal speed to 1
    else:
        mon.x = 0   # Stop horizontal movement
```

the error is : Invalid Set 'x' (on base:'bool') of value of type 'int'

I tried couple of ideas and please someone explain why and what move and slide does I'm a beginner in GDScript and I'm learning Sfml with C++ Help me on Godot please

Comment: A more descriptive title might help other with similar issues to find this question.

Comment: no im trying to implement the movement of the player left and right it seems right but in the run the problem how and crush the run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two points of interest here:

- The variable `mon` is declared without a type:

  ```
  var mon = Vector2.ZERO
  ```

  Here the variable is initialized with a `Vector2.ZERO`, but it is a Variant. Godot won't stop you from setting a variable of a different type.

  If you declare the type explicitly:

  ```
  var mon:Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO
  ```

  Or implicitly:

  ```
  var mon := Vector2.ZERO
  ```

  Then Godot will tell you when you are not setting a `Vector2` to it.
- The method `move_and_slide` returns a `bool`.

  As a result, here:

  ```
  mon = move_and_slide()
  ```

  The `mon` variable is being set to a `bool` value.

  In Godot 3.x `move_and_slide` used to return a vector with the final velocity. That is no longer true in Godot 4.x. Instead `move_and_slide` moves according to the `velocity` property, and it also updates said `velocity` property.

  The `bool` value that `move_and_slide` returns tells you if there were collisions or not.

With that said, you should be using `velocity`:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

func _physics_process(delta):
    move_and_slide()

    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x = -1  # Set the horizontal speed to -1
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x = 1   # Set the horizontal speed to 1
    else:
        velocity.x = 0   # Stop horizontal movement
```

---

I'll also note that the units of `velocity` for 2D are pixels per second. So setting its components to `1` means that it will take one second to move a pixel, which is too little to notice.

Instead, consider declaring a speed:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed := 100.0

func _physics_process(delta):
    move_and_slide()

    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x = -speed
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x = speed
    else:
        velocity.x = 0
```

Of course, set `speed` to what you want.

---

Bonus chatter: you can use `get_axis`:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed := 100.0

func _physics_process(delta):
    move_and_slide()

    velocity.x = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right") * speed
```

Note that `get_axis` method uses the strength of the inputs, so it will be sensible to analog input (such as a joystick) if configured.